# Understand the response of Open street map query response

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, mapkit, openstreetmap

I am trying to get the speed limit of the surrounding locations of a specific coordinate.

```
OSM Query: www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?*[maxspeed=*][bbox=5.6283473,50.5348043,5.6285261,50.534884]
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="Overpass API">
<note>The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL.</note>
<meta osm_base="2015-06-09T07:04:02Z"/>

  <node id="21265775" lat="50.5350159" lon="5.6293520"/>
  <node id="21265776" lat="50.5346804" lon="5.6276238"/>
  <node id="1312239857" lat="50.5347491" lon="5.6278274"/>
  <node id="1312239864" lat="50.5348877" lon="5.6286790">
    <tag k="highway" v="crossing"/>
    <tag k="traffic_calming" v="table"/>
  </node>
  <node id="2025084669" lat="50.5353414" lon="5.6303289">
    <tag k="highway" v="traffic_calming"/>
    <tag k="traffic_calming" v="choker"/>
  </node>
  <node id="3362188585" lat="50.5345623" lon="5.6274183">
    <tag k="highway" v="traffic_calming"/>
    <tag k="traffic_calming" v="choker"/>
  </node>
  <way id="191950462">
    <nd ref="2025084669"/>
    <nd ref="21265775"/>
    <nd ref="1312239864"/>
    <nd ref="1312239857"/>
    <nd ref="21265776"/>
    <nd ref="3362188585"/>
    <tag k="highway" v="secondary"/>
    <tag k="maxspeed" v="30"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Rue d'Esneux"/>
    <tag k="source:maxspeed" v="school zone"/>
  </way>

</osm>
```

This is in case of bounding box (bbox: I am guessing these are the corner coordinates or the API makes a box or polygon based on the provided coordinates). But the issue is, I have only one coordinate and another issue is, I see maxspeed = 30 in the response. But not sure what kind of code should I write to parse this response as the response format may change. I am using objective C platform to parse this response.

Comment: the above URL is not working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of the response is regular [XML](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML). For understanding it you should read about OSM's [elements](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements).

Your response contains one [way](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way) and several [nodes](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node) as well as their [tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags). But it could contain more than a single way when querying a different bounding box.

The way has a [maxspeed tag](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:maxspeed) in which you seem to be interested. The way geometry is defined by its nodes. The way referes six different nodes via `<nd ref="<node ID>"/>`. Each `<node>` has a unique ID and a coordinate specified via lat and lon. The way geometry is defined by the order in which it references its nodes, not the order in which the nodes appear in the response file! In your specific case, the way starts at the node with ID *2025084669* and ends at the node with ID *3362188585*. Also keep in mind that a single way can refer the same node more than once (e.g. if it is a roundabout). And that a single node can be referenced by more than one way (e.g. if it is a junction).

Understanding these primitives might get easier for you if you create an OSM account and try one of the map editors.

Regarding JSON output: I suggest to get rid of the XAPI compatibility call and instead start using Overpass XML or Overpass QL which are much more powerful (see the [language guide](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide)): [raw data](http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];way[%22maxspeed%22](50.5348043,5.6283473,50.534884,5.6285261);(._;%3E;);out%20body;), [query and data on overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/9T4). Note that the bounding box format here differes from the ordering in the XAPI syntax.

Comment: what if I have only one coordinate? and I am not still clear about what boundingbox actually is.

Comment: A bounding box is just a rectangle. The probability that your single coordinate exactly matches a road is almost zero. You will have to specify an area that you expect to contain a road. If the response doesn't return any road within this area then you have to increase the size of the bounding box.

Comment: Yes you can, see [choose file format](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Choose_file_format) in the Overpass API language guide.

Comment: I extended my answer accordingly.

Comment: One problem still exists.. this query only takes -90 to 90 values.. but the previous one was taking -180 to 180 for a bounding box

Comment: Please see my last sentence. The bbox format differs. You are likely mixing up latitude (-90 to 90) and longitude (-180 to 180).